# Why can't I accesses the properties of an object stored in a element of a ArrayList?

Tags: java

I have two packages lets give them the name package 1 and package 2.
Class A and Class B is in package1. Class A contains an ArrayList called PTable. Class B contains a function called query() that filters through PTable,in Class A, based on a certain conditions and returns an ArrayList called result that contains all the elements from PTable that meet that condition.

I now have package2 that contains Class C. Class C imports Class B from package 1; Class C is a subclass of HttpServlet. I create an object of Class B in class C and initializer it.

I then call the function query() and assign it to a variable called results. When I try and get the properties of an element at a certain index, I can't see the properties of the original objects stored in the ArrayList PTable.[This is what appears when I try and access the properties of the objects. My aim is to see the second image [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5LzN.png)

Comment: Sorry There is only one image and that is what shows when I try and access the properties of the object

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: There are free online Java tutorials study them -> https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java+tutorial+beginner i expect this question to be closed or deleted by our overlords. So copy the answer below to a notepad and study at your leisure!

Answer (score 1):

Nice to ask questions but first spend sometime studying Java. Read a book or online and you will learn about casting very quickly. Also about classes, super classes etc

Your storing the objects in a variable of type Element (your results array list).

Cast the object back to the type it belongs too and then you will see the variables.

Code design note : storing different types of classesin the same array list is legal and possible but bug prone. Try to avoid it. If you change the order of storing variables into the list, you need to change all the access code too. Anyway happy learning.

There are free online Java tutorials study them -> https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java+tutorial+beginner

Sample class, in the main method try to get the object at position 1 and cast it to a Person :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person() {

    }

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

class Car {

    private String manufacturer;
    private String model;
    private double price;
    private int yearOfMfr;
    private Date dateBought;
    private String licenceNumber;

    public Car() {
        super();

    }

    public Car(String manufacturer, String model, double price, int yearOfMfr, Date dateBought, String licenceNumber) {
        super();
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.model = model;
        this.price = price;
        this.yearOfMfr = yearOfMfr;
        this.dateBought = dateBought;
        this.licenceNumber = licenceNumber;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getYearOfMfr() {
        return yearOfMfr;
    }

    public void setYearOfMfr(int yearOfMfr) {
        this.yearOfMfr = yearOfMfr;
    }

    public Date getDateBought() {
        return dateBought;
    }

    public void setDateBought(Date dateBought) {
        this.dateBought = dateBought;
    }

    public String getLicenceNumber() {
        return licenceNumber;
    }

    public void setLicenceNumber(String licenceNumber) {
        this.licenceNumber = licenceNumber;
    }

}

public class DemoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> results = new ArrayList<>();
        DemoApp app = new DemoApp();
        app.fillItUp(results);

        Car acar = (Car) results.get(0);
        acar.setLicenceNumber("Flying Duck");

    }

    private void fillItUp(List<Object> results) {
        Car car = new Car("sel2in", "electric_VTOL", 540923, 2018, new Date(2018, 3, 32), "Skyprog");
        results.add(car);
        results.add(new Person("tushar", 39));

    }

}
```

Comment: That wasn't what I asked. And your solution has nothing to do with what I had a problem with. In addition, your tone at the start was rude and unnecessary.

Comment: Actually it was needed. Your question was downvoted by someone else due to that. I gave you an upvote so you can still ask, after you read the [FAQ] and search first.